# Power to plug but nothing works

Tags: electrical

Ok so I have power to my plug and it’s on its own line so I hook up a  analog multimeter to check and see how much power it is giving but it blows a fuse on my multimeter. 
Can anyone tell me what’s going on please

Comment: Was your meter set to the right settings?  Try plugging in a real load: lamp, hairdryer, etc.,

Comment: Sounds like you need to go to voltmeter school.  In the meantime, anything that says "amps" or "A", *stay the heck away from that*. Those are for low voltage DC power anyway, you would never use those when dealing with mains power.  Much easier to measure amps inductively.

Comment: the title of your post does not match the content

Comment: what are you trying to find out?

Answer (score 3):

Based on a few decades of replacing fuses in multimeters blown by students, you are attempting to measure the wrong thing (or slight possibility these days that you have a very poorly made cheap meter that does not function correctly, but really, slight .vs. applying the meter incorrectly.)

Typical cause is attempting to measure amperage in a manner that makes the meter a short-circuit until its fuse blows.

Amperage is only measured in series with a load. Voltage is measured in parallel with a load. Power requires measuring both, and is most easily achieved with a purpose-built plug-in power meter that can measure both at once, and can't be hooked up wrong.